# How to spin up a docker container for a feature branch?

Tags: git, docker, branch

Let's say we have a GIT repository with a `master` branch for the client(UI) code. Every time a developer works on a feature, he/she spins off a branch and continues to commit to that private branch till they think they are done.

Before he/she merges that branch back to the master branch, I would like to be able to spin up a docker instance with the commits from that private branch - and have it talk to the deployed server API - for testing purposes.

The idea being - after we are done testing in that docker instance we can then merge that into the master branch and delete the docker instance.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify in your Dockerfile:

- what you need to talk to your server
- a copy of your git workspace

That means you docker build your image each time you want to test your code.
At each build, you either [COPY your folder](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), or you `git clone` (but that means your image has installed git: it is better if you can avoid it, to keep said image execution environment as light as possible)

See more at "[Best practices for getting code into a container (git clone vs. copy vs. data container)](https://forums.docker.com/t/best-practices-for-getting-code-into-a-container-git-clone-vs-copy-vs-data-container/4077/3)"